# Вопрос по xss, не работает JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xss

Решил понять суть и механизм xss. Написал простенький html:

```
<html>
 <head>
      <title>
           xss
      </title>
 </head>
 <body>
      <H1>
           test
      </H1> <br />
      <?php
          echo $_GET['in'];
      ?>         
  </body> 
</html>
```

Если я обращаюсь к нему, как

```
.../index.php?in=string
```

то выводить переданную мной строку, но если пытаюсь прописать скрипт

```
.../index.php?in=<script>alert('xss here')</script>
```

то ничего не происходит.

Что я делаю не так?

P.S.: JavaScript в браузере включен

Comment: что вы ожидаете от исполнения данного кода?

Comment: @titov_andrei, ну я подразумеваю, что выполнится скрипт и покажет сообщение alert

Comment: @kBro: должно работать. Посмотрите исходный код страницы, после обращения к ней, что в нём на месте `echo $_GET['in'];` появляется?

Comment: @edem, непонятно почему, но не работает вывод строк. Чисел и объектов вывод производится

Comment: @kBro: откройте консоль разработчика в Вашем браузере и посмотрите, что он Вам пишет, когда Вы пытаетесь отобразить строки.

Comment: проходил мимо... может быть настройки безопасности PHP?

Comment: у вас не будет запускаться js, в случае записи скрипта в URL. Это выходит за рамки возможностой HTTP/HTTPS. Добавляйте Ваш js в конец body, как правильно это наиболее правильное расположение

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы используете Chrome: с подобными простыми reflected XSS справляется Chrome XSS Auditor, в таком случае на вкладке "Console" панели разработчика будут сообщения о блокировании исполнения скрипта.

Но нужно учитывать, что Chrome [не обязательно защитит от любых отраженных XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53474/is-chrome-completely-secure-against-reflected-xss), ещё можно полистать результаты поиска по "[chrome xss auditor bypass](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=chrome%20xss%20auditor%20bypass)".

Думаю, [эта игра от Google](https://xss-game.appspot.com/), где можно познакомиться с различными видами XSS, будет вам интересна.